# Server 2008 R2 GPO Lock Down - Remove Search Everywhere

Tags: group-policy

I'm trying to create a lock down GPO on a terminal server running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is there a way to get rid of that search field that is in the Start Menu? I think it is called 'Everywhere Search'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of that is located under: User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar

Other Start Menu GPO settings: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617162(WS.10).aspx

Search anywhere:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744697(WS.10).aspx#WS_RemoveSeeMoreResults